# How to get raw request that Savon sends

Tags: ruby, savon

I am using Savon 2.6 to implement a client for a SOAP service.
I have to save raw requests and raw responses in the database. 
To get raw XML response isn't a problem, but how can I get a raw XML request?

I use Savon in the following way:

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://blabla.com/bla.wdsl")
response = client.call(:operation_name, message: {param1: "a", param2: "b'})
response.to_xml # => get raw XML response
```

Comment: I don't think there is a public method for this. You should look into the source of Savon and add to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can hack the code in the [Client class](https://github.com/savonrb/savon/blob/version2/lib/savon/client.rb) and the [Operation class](https://github.com/savonrb/savon/blob/version2/lib/savon/operation.rb).

What I did was to add a method in `Operation` that returns the request.  In `Client#call` I set the request to an instance variable and added a getter for it.

Edit:
If Operation#build_request still does what it did when I first posted this more than three years ago something like:

```
def request(locals = {}, &block)
  builder = build(locals, &block)
  build_request(builder)
end
```

might be what you're looking for.

Comment: What did the method in Operation look like?

Comment: @GarryGomez I added the `build_request` method.  It looks a bit different now so check to see if it does what you need. Edit: no, what I added was a method called `request`. That got merged in but now it's not there anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Savon 2.12 and you can just use something like this to get what will be sent in the request:

```
req = client.build_request(:method_name, message: request_options)
puts req.xml
```